# window.opener.location.href get blocking error

Tags: javascript, window.opener

I've a website and there is a search option from home page. I need to open two tabs from home page search and I did this job by the following way:

```
window.location.href = 'partnerUrl'; // Other Site URL
window.open('Listing Page URL', '_blank'); // Load may site's next page (listing page)
```

and it's working fine.

Ok, now from listing page I need to check which partner link was opened from the code line `window.location.href = 'partnerUrl';`. I'm trying to do this by `window.opener.location.href` but it returns the following error:

> Exception: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin `my_site_link` from accessing a cross-origin frame. at Function.getOwnPropertyDescriptor () at process.next () at _propertyDescriptors.next ()

How can I resolve the probelm? Any of your suggestion will be appriciated.

Comment: Is the origin https and the current frame http or vice versa? This could cause the issue.

Comment: @BrianHannay both are `https`.